# Retrieving object from its hashcode.

Tags: java, tostring

I can get reference of object through toString if not overloaded for example, "com.app.MyObject@234d80". But, is there anyway to get the object if I have just the string. Is it safe ?

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. Even if there was some global map that returns an object by some key, `hashCode` wouldn't serve as that key, since two different objects can have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: just to clarify, I have heard that, "two different objects can have the same hashCode.." before also. but I have also read that hash code is a unique integers for distinct objects. Are you talking of distributed systems, or hash code generated by 2 different jvm on a single machine?

Comment: A hash code is definitely not unique. The more unique-like it is, the better, but it can't possibly be unique. Think about strings. There are an infinite number of them, right? (for instance `"a"`, `"aa"`, `"aaa"`...). But a hash code can only have 2^32 different values. That means you have to map an infinite number of strings to a finite number of values, and therefore you have to have collisions (ie, non-unique hashes)

Comment: Read this http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/.  Bottom line, unequal objects can have the same hashCode.  Hashcode returns an integer.  Surely there are more unique objects that are addressable than there are unique integer values.

Comment: @user2900314 hashCode is not unique. From the Javadoc - `It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.`

Comment: @user2900314 forget `hashCode()` and javadoc and all of Java for a minute — hashing and hash codes are a general concept applicable all across (and even outside of) programming. If you learn the [concepts of hashing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Hashing) and [collisions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Hashing#Collisions) you'll understand what you're doing better.

Answer (score 0):

There is not.

Identity hash codes are produced by converting an object's address to an integer (`int`). Since the number of addresses can be larger than the number of possible integers, there is no absolute guarantee that two different objects will have different identity hash codes.

From [`Object#hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

> **As much as is reasonably practical**, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, **but this implementation technique is not required by the Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language.**)

(Emphasis mine)